# How to create a twig custom tag that executes a callback?

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to create a custom Twig tag such as this:

```
{% mytag 'foo','bar' %}
   Hello world!!
{% endmytag %}
```

This tag should print the output of `my func("Hello world!!", "foo", "bar")`.

**Can anybody post some sample code for creating such custom tag?** One that may accept a arbitrary number of parameters would me even more appreciated.

**note**: I'm not interested in creating a custom function, I need to have the body of the tag passed in as the first parameter.

Comment: nice presentation about that from SymfonyCon Warsaw 2013 - Matthias Noback - Diving Deep Into Twig: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDM0u0B_tXo#t=611 Hope this helps.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

## Theory

Before speaking about tags, you should understand how Twig works internally.

- First, as Twig code can be put on a file, on a string or even on a database, Twig opens and reads your stream using a Loader. Most known loaders are `Twig_Loader_Filesystem` to open twig code from a file, and `Twig_Loader_Array` to get twig code directly from a string.
- Then, this twig code is parsed to build a parse tree, containing an object representation of the twig code. Each object are called `Node`, because they are part of a tree. As other languages, Twig is made of tokens, such as `{%`, `{#`, `function()`, `"string"`... so Twig language constructs will read for several tokens to build the right node.
- The parse tree is then walked across, and compiled into PHP code. The generated PHP classes follow the `Twig_Template` interface, so the renderer can call the `doDisplay` method of that class to generate the final result.

If you enable caching, you can see those generated files and understand what's going on.

---

## Let's start practicing smoothly...

All internal twig tags, such as `{% block %}`, `{% set %}`... are developed using the same interfaces as custom tags, so if you need some specific samples, you can look at Twig source code.

But, the sample you want is a good start anyway, so let's develop it.

### The TokenParser

The token parser's goal is to parse and validate your tag arguments. For example, the `{% macro %}` tag requires a name, and will crash if you give a string instead.

When Twig finds a tag, it will look into all registered `TokenParser` classes the tag name returned by `getTag()` method. If the name match, then Twig calls the `parse()` method of that  class.

When `parse()` is called, the stream pointer is still on the tag name token. So we should get all inline arguments, and finish the tag declaration by finding an `BLOCK_END_TYPE` token. Then, we subparse the tag's body (what is contained inside the tag, as it also may contain twig logic, such as tags and other stuffs): the `decideMyTagFork` method will be called each time a new tag is found in the body: and will break the sub parsing if it returns true. Note that this method name does not take part of the interface, that's just a standard used on Twig's built-in extensions.

For reference, Twig tokens can be the following:

- `EOF_TYPE`: last token of the stream, indicating the end.
- `TEXT_TYPE`: the text that does not take part of twig language: for example, in the Twig code `Hello, {{ var }}`, `hello,` is a `TEXT_TYPE` token.
- `BLOCK_START_TYPE`: the "begin to execute statement" token, `{%`
- `VAR_START_TYPE`: the "begin to get expression result" token, `{{`
- `BLOCK_END_TYPE`: the "finish to execute statement" token, `%}`
- `VAR_END_TYPE`: the "finish to get expression result" token, `}}`
- `NAME_TYPE`: this token is like a string without quotes, just like a variable name in twig, `{{ i_am_a_name_type }}`
- `NUMBER_TYPE`: nodes of this type contains number, such as 3, -2, 4.5...
- `STRING_TYPE`: contains a string encapsulated with quotes or doublequotes, such as `'foo'` and `"bar"`
- `OPERATOR_TYPE`: contains an operator, such as `+`, `-`, but also `~`, `?`... You will about never need this token as Twig already provide an expression parser.
- `INTERPOLATION_START_TYPE`, the "begin interpolation" token (since Twig >= 1.5), interpolations are expressions interpretation inside twig strings, such as `"my string, my #{variable} and 1+1 = #{1+1}"`. Beginning of the interpolation is `#{`.
- `INTERPOLATION_END_TYPE`, the "end interpolation" token (since Twig >= 1.5), unescaped `}` inside a string when an interpolation was open for instance.

<kbd>MyTagTokenParser.php</kbd>

```
<?php

class MyTagTokenParser extends \Twig_TokenParser
{

   public function parse(\Twig_Token $token)
   {
      $lineno = $token->getLine();

      $stream = $this->parser->getStream();

      // recovers all inline parameters close to your tag name
      $params = array_merge(array (), $this->getInlineParams($token));

      $continue = true;
      while ($continue)
      {
         // create subtree until the decideMyTagFork() callback returns true
         $body = $this->parser->subparse(array ($this, 'decideMyTagFork'));

         // I like to put a switch here, in case you need to add middle tags, such
         // as: {% mytag %}, {% nextmytag %}, {% endmytag %}.
         $tag = $stream->next()->getValue();

         switch ($tag)
         {
            case 'endmytag':
               $continue = false;
               break;
            default:
               throw new \Twig_Error_Syntax(sprintf('Unexpected end of template. Twig was looking for the following tags "endmytag" to close the "mytag" block started at line %d)', $lineno), -1);
         }

         // you want $body at the beginning of your arguments
         array_unshift($params, $body);

         // if your endmytag can also contains params, you can uncomment this line:
         // $params = array_merge($params, $this->getInlineParams($token));
         // and comment this one:
         $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);
      }

      return new MyTagNode(new \Twig_Node($params), $lineno, $this->getTag());
   }

   /**
    * Recovers all tag parameters until we find a BLOCK_END_TYPE ( %} )
    *
    * @param \Twig_Token $token
    * @return array
    */
   protected function getInlineParams(\Twig_Token $token)
   {
      $stream = $this->parser->getStream();
      $params = array ();
      while (!$stream->test(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE))
      {
         $params[] = $this->parser->getExpressionParser()->parseExpression();
      }
      $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);
      return $params;
   }

   /**
    * Callback called at each tag name when subparsing, must return
    * true when the expected end tag is reached.
    *
    * @param \Twig_Token $token
    * @return bool
    */
   public function decideMyTagFork(\Twig_Token $token)
   {
      return $token->test(array ('endmytag'));
   }

   /**
    * Your tag name: if the parsed tag match the one you put here, your parse()
    * method will be called.
    *
    * @return string
    */
   public function getTag()
   {
      return 'mytag';
   }

}
```

### The compiler

The compiler is the code that will write in PHP what your tag should do. In your example, you want to call a function with body as first parameter, and all tag arguments as other parameters.

As the body entered between `{% mytag %}` and `{% endmytag %}` might be complex and also compile its own code, we should trick using output buffering (`ob_start()` / `ob_get_clean()`) to fill the `functionToCall()`'s argument.

<kbd>MyTagNode.php</kbd>

```
<?php

class MyTagNode extends \Twig_Node
{

   public function __construct($params, $lineno = 0, $tag = null)
   {
      parent::__construct(array ('params' => $params), array (), $lineno, $tag);
   }

   public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler)
   {
      $count = count($this->getNode('params'));

      $compiler
         ->addDebugInfo($this);

      for ($i = 0; ($i < $count); $i++)
      {
         // argument is not an expression (such as, a \Twig_Node_Textbody)
         // we should trick with output buffering to get a valid argument to pass
         // to the functionToCall() function.
         if (!($this->getNode('params')->getNode($i) instanceof \Twig_Node_Expression))
         {
            $compiler
               ->write('ob_start();')
               ->raw(PHP_EOL);

            $compiler
               ->subcompile($this->getNode('params')->getNode($i));

            $compiler
               ->write('$_mytag[] = ob_get_clean();')
               ->raw(PHP_EOL);
         }
         else
         {
            $compiler
               ->write('$_mytag[] = ')
               ->subcompile($this->getNode('params')->getNode($i))
               ->raw(';')
               ->raw(PHP_EOL);
         }
      }

      $compiler
         ->write('call_user_func_array(')
         ->string('functionToCall')
         ->raw(', $_mytag);')
         ->raw(PHP_EOL);

      $compiler
         ->write('unset($_mytag);')
         ->raw(PHP_EOL);
   }

}
```

### The extension

That's cleaner to create an extension to expose your TokenParser, because if your extension needs more, you'll declare everything's required here.

<kbd>MyTagExtension.php</kbd>

```
<?php

class MyTagExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

   public function getTokenParsers()
   {
      return array (
              new MyTagTokenParser(),
      );
   }

   public function getName()
   {
      return 'mytag';
   }

}
```

### Let's test it!

<kbd>mytag.php</kbd>

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/Twig-1.15.1/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php');
Twig_Autoloader::register();

require_once("MyTagExtension.php");
require_once("MyTagTokenParser.php");
require_once("MyTagNode.php");

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__);

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array (
// if you want to look at the generated code, uncomment this line
// and create the ./generated directory
//        'cache' => __DIR__ . '/generated',
   ));

function functionToCall()
{
   $params = func_get_args();
   $body = array_shift($params);
   echo "body = {$body}", PHP_EOL;
   echo "params = ", implode(', ', $params), PHP_EOL;
}


$twig->addExtension(new MyTagExtension());
echo $twig->render("mytag.twig", array('firstname' => 'alain'));
```

<kbd>mytag.twig</kbd>

```
{% mytag 1 "test" (2+3) firstname %}Hello, world!{% endmytag %}
```

<kbd>Result</kbd>

```
body = Hello, world!
params = 1, test, 5, alain
```

## Going further

If you enable your cache, you can see the generated result:

```
protected function doDisplay(array $context, array $blocks = array())
{
    // line 1
    ob_start();
    echo "Hello, world!";
    $_mytag[] = ob_get_clean();
    $_mytag[] = 1;
    $_mytag[] = "test";
    $_mytag[] = (2 + 3);
    $_mytag[] = (isset($context["firstname"]) ? $context["firstname"] : null);
    call_user_func_array("functionToCall", $_mytag);
    unset($_mytag);
}
```

For this specific case, this will work even if you put others `{% mytag %}` inside a `{% mytag %}` (eg, `{% mytag %}Hello, world!{% mytag %}foo bar{% endmytag %}{% endmytag %}`). But if you're building such a tag, you will probably use more complex code, and overwrite your `$_mytag` variable by the fact it has the same name even if you're deeper in the parse tree.

So let's finish this sample by making it robust.

### The NodeVisitor

A `NodeVisitor` is like a listener: when the compiler will read the parse tree to generate code, it will enter all registered `NodeVisitor` when entering or leaving a node.

So our goal is simple: when we enter a Node of type `MyTagNode`, we'll increment a deep counter, and when we leave a Node, we'll decrement this counter. In the compiler, we will be able to use this counter to generate the right variable name to use.

<kbd>MyTagNodeVisitor.php</kbd>

```
<?php

class MyTagNodevisitor implements \Twig_NodeVisitorInterface
{

   private $counter = 0;

   public function enterNode(\Twig_NodeInterface $node, \Twig_Environment $env)
   {
      if ($node instanceof MyTagNode)
      {
         $node->setAttribute('counter', $this->counter++);
      }
      return $node;
   }

   public function leaveNode(\Twig_NodeInterface $node, \Twig_Environment $env)
   {
      if ($node instanceof MyTagNode)
      {
         $node->setAttribute('counter', $this->counter--);
      }
      return $node;
   }

   public function getPriority()
   {
      return 0;
   }

}
```

Then register the NodeVisitor in your extension:

<kbd>MyTagExtension.php</kbd>

```
class MyTagExtension
{

    // ...
    public function getNodeVisitors()
    {
        return array (
                new MyTagNodeVisitor(),
        );
    }

}
```

In the compiler, replace all `"$_mytag"` by `sprintf("$mytag[%d]", $this->getAttribute('counter'))`.

<kbd>MyTagNode.php</kbd>

```
  // ...
  // replace the compile() method by this one:

  public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler)
   {
      $count = count($this->getNode('params'));

      $compiler
         ->addDebugInfo($this);

      for ($i = 0; ($i < $count); $i++)
      {
         // argument is not an expression (such as, a \Twig_Node_Textbody)
         // we should trick with output buffering to get a valid argument to pass
         // to the functionToCall() function.
         if (!($this->getNode('params')->getNode($i) instanceof \Twig_Node_Expression))
         {
            $compiler
               ->write('ob_start();')
               ->raw(PHP_EOL);

            $compiler
               ->subcompile($this->getNode('params')->getNode($i));

            $compiler
               ->write(sprintf('$_mytag[%d][] = ob_get_clean();', $this->getAttribute('counter')))
               ->raw(PHP_EOL);
         }
         else
         {
            $compiler
               ->write(sprintf('$_mytag[%d][] = ', $this->getAttribute('counter')))
               ->subcompile($this->getNode('params')->getNode($i))
               ->raw(';')
               ->raw(PHP_EOL);
         }
      }

      $compiler
         ->write('call_user_func_array(')
         ->string('functionToCall')
         ->raw(sprintf(', $_mytag[%d]);', $this->getAttribute('counter')))
         ->raw(PHP_EOL);

      $compiler
         ->write(sprintf('unset($_mytag[%d]);', $this->getAttribute('counter')))
         ->raw(PHP_EOL);
   }
```

Don't forget to include the NodeVisitor inside the sample:

<kbd>mytag.php</kbd>

```
// ...
require_once("MyTagNodeVisitor.php");
```

## Conclusion

Custom tags are a very powerful way to extend twig, and this introduction gives you a good start. There are lots of features not described here, but by looking close to twig built-in extensions, abstract classes extended by the classes we written, and moreover by reading the generated php code resulting from twig files, you'll get everything to create any tag you want.

### [Download this sample](http://alain.ocarina.fr/medias/twig-demo-so-26170727.zip)

Comment: Absolutely wonderful: just what I needed. Waiting for StackOverflow to let me award the bounty.

Comment: Bounty awarded. Thank you!

Comment: What `$compiler->subcompile()` do ?

Comment: It will compile everything that is nested in the parse tree. For example, if you open a `{% if %}` tag, subcompile will compile the arbitrary code you can have before the `{% endif %}`.

Comment: Is it possible to return the source code (everything within the two tags) to the new function so the function can render the source? E.g. {% mytag %}{{ title }}{% endmytag %} -> the new function have the variable {{ title }} and will render the body of the tag.

Comment: No that's not possible as is, when you're processing nodes to write some php, source code is already parsed to tokens.

Comment: Which class does `functionToCall` go in?

Comment: it's a global function declared in `mytag.php`.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at documentation.. Not sure that it follows all the standards, but it works..

```
require 'Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_AutoLoader::register();

class MyTag_TokenParser extends Twig_TokenParser
{
    public function parse(Twig_Token $token)
    {
        $parser = $this->parser;
        $stream = $parser->getStream();

        if (!$stream->test(Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE))   
           $values = $this->parser->getExpressionParser()
                          ->parseMultitargetExpression();

        $stream->expect(Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);

        $body = $this->parser->subparse(array($this, 'decideMyTagEnd'), true);

        $stream->expect(Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);

        return new MyTag_Node($body, $values, $token->getLine(), $this->getTag());
    }

    public function decideMyTagEnd(Twig_Token $token)
    {
        return $token->test('endmytag');
    }

    public function getTag()
    {
        return 'mytag';
    }
}

class MyTag_Node extends Twig_Node
{
    public function __construct(Twig_NodeInterface $body, $values,
                                $line, $tag = null)
    {
        if ($values)
           parent::__construct(array('body' => $body, 'values' => $values),
                               array(), $line, $tag);
        else
           parent::__construct(array('body' => $body), array(), $line, $tag);        
    }

    public function compile(Twig_Compiler $compiler)
    {
        $compiler
            ->addDebugInfo($this)
            ->write("ob_start();\n")
            ->subcompile($this->getNode('body'))            
            ->write("my_func(ob_get_clean()");

        if ($this->hasNode('values'))
        foreach ($this->getNode('values') as $node) {
            $compiler->raw(", ")
                     ->subcompile($node);
        };

        $compiler->raw(");\n"); 
    }
}

function my_func()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    print_r($args);
}

$loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addTokenParser(new MyTag_TokenParser()); 

$template =<<<TEMPLATE
{% mytag %}
test1
{% endmytag %}

{% mytag 'var1' %}
test2
{% endmytag %}

TEMPLATE;

echo $twig->render($template);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll take a look tomorrow and let you know