# How to parse Twig custom tag arguments

Tags: parsing, twig, token

I wrote a custom Twig TagTokenParser to let me write this in my templates :

```
{% tag "tagtype" argument1="value1" argument2="value3" %}{% endtag %}
```

It works, but i would like to put dynamic attribute values :

```
{% tag "tagtype" argument1="{{ myVar.myProp }}" argument2="value3" %}{% endtag %}
```

Here is how i write my TagTokenParser:

```
        while (!$stream->test(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE)) {

        if ($stream->test(\Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE)) {
            // Read the attribute name
            $name = $stream->next()->getValue();

            // Read the "="
            $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::OPERATOR_TYPE, '=');

            // Read the attribute value
            $token = $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::STRING_TYPE);
            $value = $token->getValue();
```

How can i parse the expression locate in the \Twig_Token::STRING_TYPE token and write it in my TagNode compiler ?

I try to parse the expression as a new string, but when i loose the context when compiling it:

```
 $parameters = $this->parser->getEnvironment()->tokenize($attribute_value);
```

Or is there a way to parse the argument value as an expression ? like this :

```
$value = $parser->getExpressionParser()->parseExpression();
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse an expression instead of a string, so your variable (or even a function call, a string, a calculation or whatever) will be interpreted:

Instead of:

```
// Read the attribute value
$token = $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::STRING_TYPE);
$value = $token->getValue();
```

You should use:

```
$value = $parser->getExpressionParser()->parseExpression();
```

Then, you'll be able to use:

```
{% tag "tagtype" argument1=myVar.myProp argument2="value3" %}{% endtag %}
```

**Warning**: in your `TokenParser`, the `$value` variable will not contain the value of your variable, but a compilable expression that will retrieve the variable's value from the context at runtime.

So, in your `Node`, instead of using `$value`, you'll need to subcompile it:

```
$compiler->subcompile($this->getNode('value'));
```

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26170727/731138) for details about the subject.

Comment: Thanks ! I now understand the need of parsing the argument value as an  expression and then subcompile it within my `Node`.
But, is it possible to parse an expression in a "..." pattern ? For example : `"{{ myVar.myProp }}"` ? Using something like `$stream->skipToken('"'); $value = $parser->getExpressionParser()->parseExpression();$stream->skipToken('"');` ?

Comment: You can do string interpolation using `"#{myVar.myProp}"`.