# Custom Symfony2 filter not triggering with custom twig tag

Tags: php, symfony, dart, twig, assetic

**TL:DR;** Adding `type="application/dart"` makes Assetic ignore the filter flag `filter=MyCustomFilter`.

Removing the latter attribute type triggers `filter=MyCustomFilter` just fine. But I need the filter and the attribute. How do I make Assetic trigger my custom filter while having the `type=application/dart` attribute?

I believe part of the problem is that it only accepts `type=application/javascript` or an empty html `type` attribute for the filter to trigger. I'm not sure where to go from here.

---

#### Full details:

I want to make a tag similar to `javascripts` but for Dart files.

```
{% darts
    '@AcmeBundle/Resources/dart/AcmeMain/web/main.dart'
%}$ 
    <script type="application/dart" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% enddarts %}
```

I want to be able to use the `@` notation instead of `/bundles/etc/`

After a bit of searching, I tried the following:

I extended `Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Twig\AsseticExtension`

I inherited the following function:

```
public function getTokenParsers()
{
    return array(
        $this->createTokenParser('javascripts', 'js/*.js'),
        $this->createTokenParser('stylesheets', 'css/*.css'),
        $this->createTokenParser('image', 'images/*', true),
    );
}
```

In my own child class I added to the parent array `$this->createTokenParser('darts', 'dart/*.dart')`.

Initially this works when I have.

```
{% darts '@MyBundle\...\main.dart' filter="MyCustomFilter" %}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
```

However, the bootloader `dart.js` requires as `type="application/dart` attribute in order for the bootstrap to work.

As soon as I add the required attribute, editing the source file does not recompile. It's pretty much ignored. The following code is ignored and does not trigger `MyCustomFilter` filter:

```
{% darts '@MyBundle\...\main.dart' filter="MyCustomFilter" %}
<script type="application/dart" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
```

I can't seem to find where to go next from here, seeing how it all works is pretty overwhelming in itself. I only need it to recognize `type="application/dart` as valid so that my `MyCustomFilter` gets triggered.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#tags ?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `{% javascripts %}` tag with a dart2js filter? This way, your Dart scripts will be compiled to JavaScript, avoiding compatibility issues with browsers.

Comment: @Nic The dartbootloader doesn't work without the filename ending in `.dart`. I could modify the bootloader but everytime the bootloader gets updated I'd have to remember to modify the bootloader before my code works. That's why I'd like a proper solution.

Comment: I have no experience with Dart, but doesn't compiling it to plain old javascript remove the need for client-side compilation?

Comment: @Nic There's never any client side compilation, the dart code is compiled to javascript on the server. Anyway the way it works is that the dart bootloader `dart.js` checks for the uncompiled `main.dart`. If the browser doesn't support it, it loads `main.js`. Now, somewhere in assetic it's preventing my filter from triggering compiling the code when `type="application/dart` is added inside the `<script>` attribute. So the bootloader cannot load `main.js` because assetic never compiled in the first place.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. I just tested and with the regular `{% javascripts %}` tag I am able to use `type="application/dart"`. I did not test it with a custom `{% darts %}` tag. However, I now understand your problem a little bit better and I think I have a very simple solution for you. I'll post it in an answer to your question.

Comment: After posting the answer I see that you already mention the `output` argument in your question... However, in my case it seems to work perfectly! Files are being output as `dart/file.dart`, not `dart/file.dart.js`. Are you sure it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Well, it is getting very hard to help you without knowing more about your custom filter. Is it really called `MyCustomFilter`? And does it really work correctly when the script type is not `application/dart`? In my application, I use the `uglifyjs2` filter to minify my JavaScripts. It works fine with `<script type="application/dart">`. I don't even think that a filter can be aware of the script type. By the way, does this problem occur in production or development environment or both? Can you perhaps edit the question and post the **exact**, unmodified version of your `{% javascripts %}` tag?

Comment: @Nic Thanks for helping me improve my question. It looks like you were right. It works with the `{% javascripts %}` tag alone and that custom `application/dart` attribute. I could have sworn I had tried this before but maybe I tried it when something else was broken. Which is when I thought I perhaps needed a custom tag. Thank you. Maybe I should have started from scratch once I finished `MyCustomFilter` long ago. haha.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it works now! Thanks for the bounty!

Comment: @Nic You earned it, thanks for taking the time to think about my dumb mistake. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a very simple solution for your problem, that removes the need for a new `{% darts %}` tag.

In Assetic tags, you can specify an `output` argument, that allows you to override the default output path (which is `js/*.js` in case of the `{% javascripts %}` tag). By setting `output` to `dart/*.dart`, you not only change the directory where the files will be stored, but also the file extension.

Example:

```
{% javascripts '@AcmeBundle/Resources/dart/AcmeMain/web/main.dart' filter="MyCustomFilter" output='dart/*.dart' %}
    <script type="application/dart" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Will (in production environment) result in:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="/dart/0b13818.dart"></script>
```

This feature is described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#controlling-the-url-used) in the Symfony documentation, although it does not mention the fact that you can change the extension.

I just ran a quick test in my Symfony application and it seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: I thought I tried this and it ended up renaming it to `.dart.js`... I'll have try this again. I don't think I did the wildcard so I wonder if that makes all the difference.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. I've tried both `dart/foobar.dart` and `dart/*.dart`, they both result into files with the `.dart` extension.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try it in a while when I have free time here at work. By the way, what version of Symfony and Assetic is in your `composer.json` file?

Comment: I currently have installed Symfony 2.6.3, Assetic 1.2.1 and AsseticBundle 2.5.0. The `composer.json` requires Symfony and AsseticBundle, both with version constraint `~2.5`. The Assetic library is automatically installed as a dependency of AsseticBundle.

Comment: I confirm that this works well (checked on 2.5 to 2.7-dev) +1.

Comment: Ah yeah, I remember now this is expected. I will update the question because I forgot the the dart bootloader `dart.js` renames the extension `.dart` to `.js` which is expected. The real issue is that `filter="MyCustomFilter"` flag for assetic doesn't trigger trigger the filter (this filter compiles dart into JS code) when `type="application/dart"` is present. So the `dart.js` bootloader can't load the compiled JS code because it never got compiled.

Comment: I didn't even need the `output` argument. I just needed to switch back to the `{% javascripts %}` tag. For crying out loud :(. If only I hadn't thought I had already tried this.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to have a look to `vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/` files as it contains the `{% javascripts %}` implementation.

From that bundle's `Resources/config/templating_twig.yml`, they inject a service named `@templating.name_parser`, it looks like that's just what you are looking for.

You can have a try in a controller to do:

```
var_dump(
  $this
    ->get('templating.name_parser')
    ->parse('@AcmeBundle/Resources/dart/AcmeMain/web/main.dart')
    ->getPath()
);
```

About the tag itself, you can heavily copy/paste from the assetic bundle. And get some explanations about custom tags over one of my previous answers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26215387/731138).

Comment: I got closer but unfortunately I've stumbled upon another roadblock. I updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Would you mind taking one last look at my updated answer before the bounty is awarded? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: HI, I'll check that tomorrow morning. Sorry, didn't had much time this week.

Comment: Well, your issue looks specific to dart, not twig, and I really don't know dart. Are the `asset_url`s valid in the rendered views?

Comment: Thing is that twig doesn't seem to trigger filters if it's not `application/javascript`. so it's not specific to dart. I can't seem to find where I can change it to allow `application/dart` to trigger assetic filters