# How to get variable in Token Parser in Twig Extension

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm having trouble getting the correct data passed in my twig extension

Example token parser `parse` function:

```
public function parse(\Twig_Token $token)
{
    $parser = $this->parser;
    $stream = $parser->getStream();

    $firstVariable = $stream->getCurrent();    
}
```

The expression `{% myTag "someString" %}`will set `$firstVariable` as 'someString'.

However if we put in place a variable:

```
{% set someVariable = "someString" %}
{% myTag someVariable %}
```

You end up with a name type with the value 'someVariable' instead of the expected variable value 'someString'

How do I properly parse the first argument of my custom twig tag, allowing the input to either be a string or a variable containing a string?

**Edit**

It looks like you can just take the variable name and use it in the returned twig node.

```
public function compile(){
    $compiler->write('echo "$context[$variableName]"');
}
```

But I need access to it before compiling.

**Edit**
I no longer believe it's possible to access the context before compiling. Making this question a dud unless anyone has some more information to share on the subject

Comment: Yes, twig code is first converted to a parse tree, then compiled, then executed. So you can't access a variable's value until runtime. I wrote a complete answer about the subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26215387/731138).