# How to create custom tag block in twig?

Tags: php, twig

I'm using twig template for my project. now i want create custom block for example

```
{% addscript %}
<script>
//here is my content script
</script>
{% endaddscript %}
```

also {% addscript 'footer' %}{% endaddscript %} or {% addscript 'header' %}{% endaddscript %} is good

and the script content will be parse into my php function called addScript

```
Class Theme{
      private $css = array();
      public function addScript($script){
        $this->css[] = $script;
      }
}
```

after one day search and read document in twig i found this topic but does not work !
[How to create a twig custom tag that executes a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170727/how-to-create-a-twig-custom-tag-that-executes-a-callback?rq=1)

i'm using latest version of twig install by composer

Comment: Unclear what you are asking... What does the new tag need to do?

Comment: Are you read my question ?

Comment: Yes and we don't understand it. Why do you want argument 'header' in your block `addscript 'header' `

Comment: I read the question and have no clue of what you want. Especially when I read your `template` and `php` togheter. `script` and `css` have no relation with each other

Comment: Thanks you @DarkBee, i think for my poor in english ! you can read my include link , i mean create new tag in twig an executes a callback php function ! example: in content.twig we have some script , but i don't want script in html content , i want put all script to footer . are you understand

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell from the comments, is that you don't need a custom `Tag` to do what you want. You can just use `blocks` for this, `tags` are used to modify the compiled version of a template, not the content of it.

---

<kbd>base.twig.html</kbd>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ title | default('Hello World') }}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
        {% block css %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
    {% block body %}
        <nav>
        {% block navigation %}
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
        {% endblock navigation %}
        </nav>
        <section id="container">
            <section id="content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
    {% endblock body %}
    {% block scripts %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block javascript %}
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

---

<kbd>child.twig.html</kbd>

```
{% extends "base.twig.html" %}
{% block css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="child.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello Child</h1>
{% endblock %}


{% block javascript %}
<script>
    $(function() {
        console.log('Hello Child');
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yes ! that right @DarkBee , but i need get content in block css in child.twig.html and parse it into php code !

Comment: Eloborate please, you get the different stylesheets from a class/function?