# Many classes in class attribute and max 80 characters in one line

Tags: php, html, css, symfony, twig

I need to add many long classes to `class` attribute, so for now it looks like this:

```
<div class="single_text_block--content single_text_block--content--60p single_text_block--content--bigger center-block text_content">
   /* content */
</div>
```

It is hard to make it maintainable in that way. What is the best way to format this code in editor while setting max 80 characters in one line of code?

I tried this approach:

```
<div class="
    single_text_block--content
    single_text_block--content--60p
    single_text_block--content--bigger
    center-block text_content
">
```

But it makes many spaces. This is what is looks like in inside browser:

[image]

I'm using **Twig** here as my views templating engine, so I used `{% spaceless %}` but it's only working on HTML tags and is removing ALL spaces (what I need, is to change many spaces to one).

Comment: Only thing I can think about is doing something like [this](http://twigfiddle.com/ltub4a)

Comment: @DarkBee Yeah, I also thought about this ;).

Comment: @DarkBee But the disadvantage of that solution is that I wouldn't be able to find usages for this classes from CSS/SASS file. Only with "search project for" option. And also "go to class" would either not work (CTRL + B shortcut).

Comment: You could create your own tag that strip spaces and converts PHP_EOL to one space I guess

Comment: @DarkBee This could be hard... :/

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve something by creating you own `Tag` for `Twig`.
Below I have created the tag for you, currently there is still an extra space before and behind the `"`'s of the class attribute:

```
 <div class=" single_text_block--content single_text_block--content--60p single_text_block--content--bigger center-block text_content ">
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170727/how-to-create-a-twig-custom-tag-that-executes-a-callback?rq=1) is some more in-depth details on tags and how to register them into `Twig`

---

<kbd>MyProject/Twig/MyTwigExtension.php</kbd>

```
<?php
    namespace MyProject\Twig;

    class MyTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension {

    public function getTokenParsers() {
            return [
                new \MyProject\TokenParser\OneLine(),
            ];
        }

        public function getName() {
            return 'MyTwigExtension';
        }

    }
```

<kbd>MyProject/Twig/TokenParser/OneLine.php</kbd>

```
<?php
    namespace MyProject\Twig\TokenParser;

    use \MyProject\Twig\Node\OneLine as OneLineNode;

    class OneLine extends \Twig_TokenParser
    {
        public function decideOneLineEnd(\Twig_Token $token)
        {
            return $token->test('endoneline');
        }

        public function getTag()
        {
            return 'oneline';
        }

        public function parse(\Twig_Token $token)
        {
            $lineno = $token->getLine();
            $stream = $this->parser->getStream();
            $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);
            $body = $this->parser->subparse(array($this, 'decideOneLineEnd'), true);
            $stream->expect(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);

            return new OneLineNode($body, $lineno, $this->getTag());
        }
    }
```

<kbd>MyProject/Twig/Node/OneLine.php</kbd>

```
<?php
    namespace MyProject\Twig\Node;

    class OneLine extends \Twig_Node {
        public function __construct(\Twig_NodeInterface $body, $lineno, $tag = null) {
            parent::__construct(['body' => $body,], array(), $lineno, $tag);
        }

        public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler) {
            $compiler
                ->addDebugInfo($this)
                ->write('ob_start();')
                ->write(PHP_EOL)
                ->subcompile($this->getNode('body'))
                ->write(PHP_EOL)
                ->write('echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, \' \', preg_replace(\'!\s+!\', \' \', ob_get_clean()));')
                ->write(PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
```

<kbd>template.twig.html</kbd>

```
{% oneline %}
    <div class="
         single_text_block--content
         single_text_block--content--60p
         single_text_block--content--bigger
         center-block text_content
    ">
{% endoneline %}
```