# How to add variables to custom Twig's TokenParser?

Tags: twig

I want to make custom twig tag, similar to include tag, but take variables from json file. I.e. in twig template I write {% section "header" %}, and it includes header file and attach variables from config.json file to only this template. How to accomplish it?

I read [How to create a twig custom tag that executes a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170727/how-to-create-a-twig-custom-tag-that-executes-a-callback) few times before write this question, but didn't find any specific solution how to solve my issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a twig custom tag that executes a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170727/how-to-create-a-twig-custom-tag-that-executes-a-callback)

Comment: No, it's not the same

Comment: It good tutorial to get your node started. To pass arguments to your node I suggest you have look into the [Block](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/46764421/) node, `$name = $stream->expect(Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE)->getValue();`

Comment: I agree it is wonderful tutorial. And it was very helpful guide to create custom tag. The issue I'm stuck is, can't find way how to add variables to parser. Not from template( like {% include with { 'foo': 'bar'} %}), but insert from other source while parsing or compiling nodes

Comment: And you want to be able to use the externals variables inside the defined node?

Comment: Yes. The idea is, for example, I have settings.json file, where is like { 'sections' : [ { 'header' : { 'title': 'foobar' } } ] }. Then in twig file I insert  {% section 'header' %}, php code automatically include header.twig file and add variables from json file. Then in header.twig file I could use  {{ header.title }}.

Comment: I'll post a mockup of what you can do

Comment: It would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i've created a small mockup that should help you further on this path,

<kbd>MyNode.php</kbd>

```
<?php
    namespace Namespace\Base\Twig\Node;

    class MyNode extends \Twig_Node {
        private static $nodeCount = 1;
        /**
         * @param \Twig_Node_Expression $annotation
         * @param \Twig_Node_Expression $keyInfo
         * @param \Twig_NodeInterface   $body
         * @param integer               $lineno
         * @param string                $tag
         */
        public function __construct(\Twig_NodeInterface $body, $lineno, $tag = null) {
            parent::__construct(['body' => $body,], array(), $lineno, $tag);
        }

        public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler) {
            $i = self::$nodeCount ++;

            $json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../../../files/tmp/file.json'), true);
            $compiler
                ->addDebugInfo($this)
                ->write('$context[\'injected_variable\'] = '.var_export($json_data, true).';') //add data to context
                ->subcompile($this->getNode('body')) //compile everything in between the node
                ->write('unset($context[\'injected_variable\']);'); //clean context afterwards
        }
    }
```

<kbd>file.json</kbd>

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>template.twig</kbd>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        {% mynode%}
            {{ injected_variable.glossary.title }} {# prints example glossary  #}
        {% endmynode %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!