# Create a new tag from another one

Tags: twig

I would like to create a new twig tag from another one,
for the moment i use the include tag like this :

```
{% include "page/to/include.twig" %}
```

This works perfectly but now I want to automatically add html comments around the included page, something like that :

```
{% mytag "page/to/include.twig" %}
```

that will output something like :

```
<!-- mycomment : twig filename -->
  <div>My twig file contents</div>
<!-- mycomment -->
```

Comment: Create a custom [node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170727/how-to-create-a-twig-custom-tag-that-executes-a-callback) that extends from the default [include](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/lib/Twig/Node/Include.php) node. Overwrite the `compile` function

Comment: Hi @DarkBee where should i include my newly created class ?

Comment: Watch the [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26215387/446594) on how to create a basic node before creating one that extends of `include`

Comment: Ok thank you for these indications :)

Comment: @DarkBee, last question : i'm using twig as a yii2 extension, requiring it with composer, but i do not know where should i place my own custom filter files and tags...

Comment: This is just a preference, I place my custom `Twig` classes under `My\Namespace\Twig\Node`, `My\Namespace\Twig\TokenParser`, ...