# Twig custom ignore tag

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How could I create a custom comment tag?

```
{% comment %}
All of this is ignored
{% endcomment %}
```

I realize I can also use comments, but for some reasons (mostly for learning), I wanted to try this instead. I've tried multiple times by following several tutorials online, but I can't seem to figure out where to even start as I don't seem to understand what to pass into Twig_Node's __constructor and where to go from there.

As an aside, am I restricted to only being able to set custom tags as defined within `{% %}`? Or does twig give access to create a tag like this?

```
<twigcomment>
All of this is ignored
</twigcomment>
```

Comment: you must add a twig filter for it

Comment: @Sysix a `Twig_Node`, not a filter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a twig custom tag that executes a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170727/how-to-create-a-twig-custom-tag-that-executes-a-callback)